# I have made a massive mistake

Tags: tokens

Hi I sent tokens from MEW to a wrong address. My first transaction!
0x70a72833d6bf7f508c8224ce59ea1ef3d0ea3a38

Is there anyway I can get it back or locate the institution or person?

Yours weepingly
MJC

Comment: Can you provide a transaction hash?

Comment: Thanks Roman sorry as you can see I'm all very new to this and dont expect any sympathy just scorn! Here is my transaction hash

Comment: 0xdc3e9a82c4aac374cc8ee76c840401cdaee2b0677d9d54ac86bbd820af2bfc7f

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that contract doesn't have functionality to move tokens that belong to it, so there's nothing you can do. I hope the amount lost wasn't substantial.